# Given a list, find K different elements such that their sum is S

Tags: java, algorithm

I know that when asked to find two elements whose add up to a given number then the solution can be obtained in `O(n)` time, namely by making a hashmap and when iterating over the list, simply find an element such that `a[j]=S - l[i]`.  I want to be able to generalize this to `K` distinct elements.  How would i approach such a problem?  Recursively, nested loops?  I'm assuming that the best complexity in this case will be `O(n^{k-1})`, is this intuition also correct?

Comment: This has more to do with computer science than Java in particular; SO has a dedicated site for this, you'll probably have better answers over there...

Answer (score 0):

The straight-forward adaptation of this algorithm is the following:

When iterating over the list, instead of finding one element `e` with `S = e + l[i]`, find `k` elements `e[j]` with `S = Sum e[j] + l[i]`.

```
sums <- HashMap<Number, Set<Number>>
put (0, { }) into sums  //we can achieve a sum of 0 with no element
for j from 1 to k - 1 //number of elements to use
    newSums <- HashMap<Number, Set<Number>>
    for i from 0 to n - 1
        for each entry (sum, elements) in sums //iterate every combination of j elements
        newSum <- l[i] + sum
        if not newSums contains newSum
            newSums.add (newSum, elements union { i })
    next
    swap(sums, newSums)
next
for i from 0 to n - 1
    lookingForSum <- S - l[i]
    if sums contains lookingForSum
        return sums[lookingForSum] union { i }
next
```

The critical part is that `sums` may become very large. After the first iteration (`k=1`), there are `n` different sums (if all entries are different). Hence, the second iteration runs `n * n` times, producing at most `n * (n + 1) / 2` different sums (or `O(n^2)`). Then, the third iteration runs `n * O(n^2) = O(n^3)` times, and so on. So the overall time complexity is indeed `O(n^{k-1})`.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT: I realize the following algorithm allows duplicates as well. So, yes, I think the complexity will  increase to `O(n^(k-1))` if only unique elements need to be considered.*

This question depends whether `k` is even or odd. For instance, consider `k` to be 3, i.e. a+b+c = S, where a,b,c belong to the array. By brute force, we know that the complexity will be `O(n^3)`. However, if you store all the array elements in a set, all we need to find is to see if S - (a+b) is present in the set. This gives us `O(n^2)` complexity.

Now if you consider k = 4, if you realize, all you need to do is to compute a set `R` of *sums of all 2-element subsets of the original array* (makes sense?). Then, for every two elements a and b in the original array, check if S−a−b is in `R`. That again gives us `O(n^2)` algorithm for `k = 4`.

Drawing similar intuition, when `k` is `even`, all we need to do are:

1. Determine a set `R` that stores all the *sums of all the `k/2-element tuples` of the original array*.
2. For every `k/2` tuple of elements in the original array, compute its sum, say `s`. If `S - s ∈ R`, a solution is present.

The complexity thus is `O(n^(k/2))`

When `k` is `odd`, only a slight modification is required.

1. For the first step, `sums of all (k-1)/2 - tuples` of the original array are stored in `R`.
2. For every `(k+1)/2` tuple of elements in the original array, compute its sum, say `s`. If `S - s ∈ R`, a solution is present.

Complexity will be `O(n ^ (k+1)/2 )`